# Removing middle fourths instead of middle thirds in Cantor Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If you removed middle fourths instead of middle thirds to form a generalized Cantor set G, then what would the Lebesgue measure $m(G)$?

The geometric series that I obtained from removing middle fourths was:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}+(2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{8})+\big(4\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\big(\frac{3}{8}\big)^2\big)+\big(8\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\big(\frac{3}{8}\big)^3\big)+\dots$

$=\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}+(\frac{1}{2}).(\frac{3}{8})+\big(\frac{3}{8}\big)^2+2\cdot\big(\frac{3}{8}\big)^3+4\cdot\big(\frac{3}{8}\big)^4+\dots$

$=\displaystyle\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{1-\big(2\cdot\frac{3}{8}\big)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{1-\frac{6}{8}}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{2}{8}}=1$

Did I arrive at the answer correctly? Is my geometric series correct? Any critiques are appreciated.

Comment: Sure. In fact, if you remove the middle $p$, then you remove a set of full measure and you're left with a set of measure zero.

Comment: This Cantor set " removing middle 1/4th proportion each time:---is Called " C ( sub 1/4).Please see Pertri Mattilla; FourierAnalysis and Hausdorff dimension; 2015 Cambridge UPress; and also his 1995 Cambridge book. There are also more recent ones by Peres andBishop ;others for further results

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your geometric series is correct and your new Cantor dust has measure zero.

You may try different middle intervals to remove and get different Cantor dusts with the same measure.

Note that while these Cantor sets have the same measure, their fractal dimensions are quite different.